# Gathering Identity in AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, web-services, security

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've spent too much time with SharePoint recently which handles identity for you :)

If I have a voting system that I want to construct around AJAX calls, how do I get the users identity?

I don't (to my knowledge) have access to session in Web Services. I want to make the users identity a field that is assigned automatically by the server to protect from vote fraud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HttpContext.Current.Session to access session in Webservice and Webmethod